# How expose different ports on the same IP at GCE

Tags: gitlab, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are **trying to host a service** which **needs to expose at least two different ports on the same address** on GCE.

In our case this is GitLab, which should at least provide SSH (Port 22) and HTTPS (Port 443) access. But in fact this could be any service that needs two or more ports on the same Domain or IP address.

The service is running fine inside a GCE VM instance and I'm looking for the most sensible way to expose it to the world. Of course **HTTPS is mandatory** for any production deployment like this. I'd prefer not to handle TLS on the instance for convenince and security reasons.

All the different options we found to expose this service aren't perfect:

- Using a public IP on the instance
- Using a L4 LoadBalancer (TCP)
- Using a L7 LoadBalancer (HTTPS)

**Using a public IP on the instance**

This means exposing the service ports directly. In this case the service on the VM needs to bind to the well-known ports (22, 443). In our case that is a little annoying since the service is running within Docker and Port 22 colides with the SSH server on the host. So we'd have to use another SSH port for the host and handle TLS certificates ourself. Not so great.

**Using a L4 LoadBalancer (TCP)**

Basically the same limitations apply since it looks like the L4 LB forwards the traffic to the same ports as it receives them on. Also this option adds quite some overhead for the LoadBalancer configuration. And we still need to manage HTTPS on the instance.

**Using a L7 LoadBalancer (HTTPS)**

This is one is rather flexible but we'd loose the ability to offer SSH, which is a no-go for us.

My **Question**: **Is there a better way to expose this kind of service on GCE?**

*On AWS you can just have an ELB with multiple listener (HTTPS and TCP:22) pointing to arbitrary ports on a single instance. Also the ELB can terminate HTTPS for you. I can't really imagine that GCE does not offer a feature like this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is port redirection, e.g., exposing port 2443 to the public, but your service is listening on 443 internally. You can do this:

1) Configure iptables for port redirection on your VM:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport <public-port> -j REDIRECT --to-port <internal-port>
```

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/

2) Create a GCE firewall rule to allow the public port:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create <name> --allow tcp:<public-port> --network <network> --source-ranges "0.0.0.0/0"
```

Comment: What I miss with GCE is a way to redirect a public port to another internal port. I could probably redirect request to a specific IP address (iptables -d) but this sounds quite fragile. I was actually looking for a GCE solution.

Comment: I agree, it should be a managed service, but at this moment we have to use iptables on GCE.